# Warning: unlink(test): No such file or directory, despite not being called

Tags: php

So I'm making an attempt to remove links from the database, both image path and video link. I have given each type of file a code, 5 for videos, 2 and 1 for images. I have the following if statement to account for it:

```
if($mCode = 2 || $mCode = 1){
    unlink($mLoc); // delete image from directory
}
```

For my video link, however, which has an mCode of 5, whenever i try to remove it, it removes the file, but I get this warning:

> Warning: unlink(test): No such file or directory

Why is it still passing through the if statement? Or how could I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a single `=` you will set the $mCode.
Use `==` for loose validation
Use `===` for strict validation (includes the datatype validation)

```
if($mCode == 2 || $mCode == 1){
    unlink($mLoc); // delete image from directory
}
```

Comment: It pains me that I didn't think of this. Thank you so much.